# link luajit bytecode as dynamic library

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, luajit

I have:

```
--main.lua
print("Hello from main.lua")


//main.c
#include <stdio.h>

#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lualib.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int status;
  lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
  luaL_openlibs(L);
  lua_getglobal(L, "require");
  lua_pushliteral(L, "main");
  status = lua_pcall(L, 1, 0, 0);
  if (status) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}


#make.sh
luajit -b main.lua main.o
gcc -shared -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wl,-E -o libmyluastuff.so main.o
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wl,-E -o out main.c -I/usr/include/luajit-2.0 -lluajit-5.1 -lm -ldl -L. -lmyluastuff
rm -r dist
mkdir dist
cp out libmyluastuff.so dist
cd dist
./out
```

if i link the luajit-generated object into my binary, it works as expected, but if i link it as a library (still exporting with `-Wl,-E` as you can see), i get `Error: module 'main' not found`.

what do I do wrong?

**EDIT:**

the resulting executable isn't linked to the library at all:

```
$ ldd out 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdfadf1000)
    libluajit-5.1.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libluajit-5.1.so.2 (0x00007f52099b0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f52095e6000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f52092de000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f52090da000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5208ec4000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5209c1f000)
```

i suspect gcc just optimizes it away, cause main.c doesn't directly use any symbols from it (but libluajit would if they were linked). can i force it to link it anyway?

Comment: It might be that since the symbol is in the shared library, the executable itself doesn't export it, so LuaJIT doesn't find it. Try making sure that `.` is in `package.cpath`, requiring it from the shared library with `require("main")`.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo the problem is i don't want to use the `package.cpath` logic for loading it from that library, but want the symbols to be "just there" when the executable is linked against it and loaded by `ld`. (which it happens to be not, see edit)